# Binary sequences without optimal autocorrelation

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, coding-theory

A binary sequence of period $n$ is a sequence $\{s(t)\}$ with $t=0,1,\ldots,n-1$ and $s(t)\in \{0,1\}$. For these sequences define its autocorrelation function in the usual way. For instance, if $n$ is congruent with $0$ modulo $4$, we say that the sequence has optimal autocorrelation if the maximum absolute value of its non-trivial autocorrelations is equal to $4$.

Do binary sequences without optimal autocorrelation have any application or practical importance?

*From @kodlu: Inserted from Comment (Why couldn't you do this yourself?). Please insert any information you have about the full distribution of the correlation*

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline n & \text{autocorrelation}\\ \hline 6 & 8 \\ 7 & 16 \\ 8 & 28 \\ 9 & 40\\ \hline \end{array}$$

Comment: I fail to see why the off-peak value of 4 is *optimal* when it is even possible to obtain an off-peak value of zero. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the sequence has applications in communication theory if all the non-trivial autocorrelation of the sequence are of small value. These sequences are used as preamble for detecting start of a physical layer packet. Packet is a term used for bunch of bits we want to transmit and receive and decode. Lets say we transmit $s(0),...,s(n-1)$ at the beginning of the packet. At receiver we want to correlate the sequence $s(0),...,s(n-1)$ with received sequence and if correlation is maximum we want to declare packet has been received. If the sequence has no optimal "non-trivial" autocorrelation then at the receiver correlation has only one peak so easy to detect and if non-trivial autocorrelation are small, then we can even avoid false packet detection by putting a threshold on all  non-trivial autocorrelation to be small.

So if you have such a sequence, you can use it as preamble sequence at the beginning of packet and this sequence can be used to detect the start of the packet.
Note that you need to repeat the sequence at the beginning of the packet to make it periodic and then transmit.

Good Luck !

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!

Do you have a paper where they talk about binary sequences without optimal autocorrelation and their applications, to better understand this topic.

Comment: Dont have any papers. By the way i assumed all "non-trivial" autocorrelations are small values in my answer. This is the property i assumed for these sequences.

Comment: search for STF sequence (Short Training Field). This is the preamble sequence in Wifi or WLAN.

Comment: For example, in the work I am doing I have found sequences of period $2^n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ whose minimum value for the expression
$$\max_{\omega\in\mathbb{Z}_{2^n}\setminus{\{0\}}}\left|\mathcal{C}_s(\omega)\right|$$
where $\mathcal{C}_s(\omega)$ is the autocorrelation function at shift $\omega$, it is given in the following table:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}\hline
$n$ & \text{autocorrelation}\\ \hline
6 & 8 \\
7 & 16 \\
8 & 28 \\
9 & 40\\ \hline
  \end{tabulate}

Comment: Certainly the autocorrelation of these sequences is not optimal. Could you say that these sequences have any value in applications like the one you describe?

Comment: Please enter your table into the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

*Those peak magnitude values are not that great, so any application will depend on the distribution of the correlation. Can you supply more information about the full distribution as well? And do it in the question itself?*

*The reason is, if those bad values are spread out, i.e., if $|C_s(\omega)|$ is actually small for $\omega$ near zero, say $\omega \in (-T,T) \subseteq \{0\},$ then you have what's called a low correlation zone which means in communication applications such as synchronous CDMA the sequences may have some use. It will also depend on what this small value is, since sequences with autocorrelation zero or at most 1 in the low correlation zone are common.*

This question can be answered in two ways. If the alphabet is $\{0,1\}$ and the autocorrelation is defined by
$$
\theta(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x[k]x[k+t]
$$
where the addition in the index is mod $N$ (the period) then this is quite a different situation compared to
$$
\theta(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} (-1)^{x[k]+x[k+t]}.
$$
The second is applicable to wi-fi and cellular sequences, preambles, etc. since the actual sequence is transmitted by BPSK. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_length_sequence.

The first is typically used for optical transmission, also called OOK (on off keying).

You also need to motivate your question further. Are you asking if non-optimal sequences are of practical interest? Theoretical interest? Please put your table into the question and *clarify* your definition of correlation instead of the vague, "the usual way".

Comment: Yes, I am interested in knowing what you say: "I am asking if non-optimal sequences are of practical interest or theoretical interest"

Comment: And I'm using the second definition of autocorrelation that you give.

Comment: @JulianOsorio OK, please enter the table in your comment into the question so it is self-contained. Comments are sometimes deleted by moderators. I will write a detailed answer tomorrow

Comment: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline n & \text{autocorrelation}\\ \hline 6 & 8 \\ 7 & 16 \\ 8 & 28 \\ 9 & 40\\ \hline \end{array}$$